# Metapost: text along a line

Tags: paths, metapost, text

Followed is a small code to show text `along` a line. The "bar" is what I want. My question is how I can get the "bar" case no matter from "A to B" or "B to A'.

Generally, I want to draw a line and text along the line. To be convenient (no need of thinking about which point is the start point or end point), the text's angle is same to that of the line, no relating to `from -- to`.Thank you.

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
prologues := 1 ;

beginfig(1)
  pair A, B;
  A = (0,0);
  B = (3cm,3cm);
  draw A -- B;
  label.top ("foo", origin) rotated angle(A-B) shifted 1/2[A, B];
  label.top ("bar", origin) rotated angle(B-A) shifted 1/2[A, B];
endfig;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better what you want.  You need to know the start and end in the correct order to specify which direction to write along the line.  Are you perhaps looking to force the angles to be between -90 and +90 degrees (so the text is roughly left to right)?

Comment: @ Andrew, I know the start and end point determine the direction. In my case, the "bar" is the only I want. Is it possible? On the other hand, the degree could be -180~+180 degrees. But you are right that the text is roughly left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the text to go roughly left to right, you can add 180 degrees to the angle when it is not in the interval -90 to 90.  (As far as I can tell the output of `angle` lies in the interval -180 to 180.)

[image: Sample output]

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
prologues := 3 ;

beginfig(1)
  pair A, B, X, Y;
  numeric ang;
  def angletoright(expr P, Q) =
    begingroup save ang;
      ang := angle(P-Q);
      if (ang <=-90) or (ang > 90): ang+180 else: ang fi
    endgroup
  enddef;
  A = (0,0);
  B = (3cm,3cm);
  draw A -- B;
  label.top ("bar", origin) rotated angletoright(B,A) shifted 1/2[A,B];
  X = A shifted (.5cm,0);
  Y = B shifted (.5cm,0);
  draw X -- Y;
  label.top ("foo", origin) rotated angletoright(X,Y) shifted 1/2[X,Y];
endfig;

end
```

An alternative definition for `angletoright` is to take the difference vector and ensure that its `xpart` is positive and then compute the angle:

```
  def lefttoright(expr P, Q) =
    begingroup save Z; pair Z;
      Z := P-Q;
      if (xpart Z) < 0: -Z else: Z fi
    endgroup
  enddef;
  def angletoright(expr P, Q) =
    angle(lefttoright(P,Q))
  enddef;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Glad to know the scope of `angle` function.